# Rest Sharp DateTime deserialization

Tags: c#, .net, json, deserialization, restsharp

I'm having following problem using Rest Sharp default json deserialization

I have the following User class

```
public partial class User
 { 
  public long Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
 }
```

and following json message:

```
[
    {   "id":1,
        "name":"Adam",
        "date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
    }
]
```

By default Rest Sharp serialize this date to DateTime min value {01/01/0001 00:00:00} but how can I override this behaviour and get null in this case?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to do it in the setter itself?

Comment: It would be but it doesn't sound clean to me to do this in User class

Answer (score 0):

It appears that [RestSharp's JSON serializer](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/SimpleJson.cs) doesn't handle nullable dates the way you'd expect. Here's the relevant code:

```
if (type == typeof(DateTime) || (ReflectionUtils.IsNullableType(type) && Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) == typeof(DateTime)))
    return DateTime.ParseExact(str, Iso8601Format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal | DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);

if (type == typeof(DateTimeOffset) || (ReflectionUtils.IsNullableType(type) && Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) == typeof(DateTimeOffset)))
    return DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(str, Iso8601Format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal | DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
```

That's basically saying that for both non-nullable and nullable date properties, parse to the non-nullable type.

So your choices are to customize the deserialization behavior (information [here](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Deserialization)), or deserialize the response using something that does support nullable dates, such as [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json). Another option is to use my [Flurl](http://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/) library, an alternative to RestSharp that uses Json.NET under the hood.